# study year of that student

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Question was:

average grade for the whole study year of that student.

```
Select FirstName,LastName,Year,AverageGrade,
Avg AverageGrade Order by YearAverageGrade
from Student
```

Comment: 1) Please don't use images for data, either use formatted text or DDL/DML statements. 2) What is your question? If the results are wrong, show us what the results should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a `PARTITION BY` clause. Unless you tell SQL server what the window is, it will use the entire dataset (it can't read your mind, and guess what you're after). I also doubt you need the `ORDER BY` in the window (as that would default to `ORDER BY [Year] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`). I assume you therefore want this:

```sql
SELECT FirstName,
       LastName,
       [Year],
       AverageGrade,
       AVG(AverageGrade) OVER (PARTITION BY [Year]) AS YearAverageGrade
FROM dbo.Student;
```